# Flask Heroku Staging and Production builds

Tags: python, heroku, flask

I am new to Python, and was wondering if there is a way i can manage profiles for staging or production ? What is the best way to do this other than changing the code every time ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no "best" way to do pretty much anything in programming (since "best" is often a subjective idea, and every programmer and project is different), but since you've thrown on a Heroku tag, I assume that you need a way that works on Heroku. Therefore, I will give you [the advice that Heroku itself gives you](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars):

> A given codebase may have numerous deployments: a production site, a
>   staging site, and any number of local environments maintained by each
>   developer. An open source app may have hundreds or thousands of
>   deployments.
>
> Although all running the same code, each of these deploys have
>   environment-specific configurations. One example would be credentials
>   for an external service, such as Amazon S3. Developers may share one
>   S3 account, while the staging site and production sites each have
>   their own keys.
>
> The traditional approach for handling such config vars is to put them
>   under source - in a properties file of some sort. This is an
>   error-prone process, and is especially complicated for open source
>   apps which often have to maintain separate (and private) branches with
>   app-specific configurations.
>
> A better solution is to use environment variables, and keep the keys
>   out of the code.

How you set the environment variables for your application in your development environment is dependent on which platform you are running on (setting environment variables is different between Linux and Windows, for example). You should look at the Heroku docs for more info.

In your code, you could then use the [`os.environ`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.environ) dictionary to retrieve the environment variables.